# Write indented text to a file

Tags: java

I would like to save text to a file such that certain paragraphs are indented (each line of the paragraph is indented). I'm using `BufferedWriter` or `Scanner` or whatever. How would I go about doing this without counting characters?

Comment: Well, what classes are you using? Why do you need to count characters?  Have you made any attempts already? If so, can we see your code?

Comment: I'm using BufferedWriter, but I'm down for whatever. I haven't made any attempts because I was incapable of finding the appropriate class to use. I don't think I need to count characters, but it is a viable hack. Thank you socrates.

Comment: You need an algorithm to determine the indentation of a given paragraph.  Do you have that?

Comment: I could write it. There's no API tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to find all newlines, and insert the appropriate number of spaces after each newline.

So, the code will always need to look at each character, and possibly also parsing the text in order find where and how much to indent.

You can implement your `java.io.Writer` that handles the parsing and formatting. Even though the most efficient way is to work directly on char buffers, it is also a lot more complicated than just creating a new String and use the String functions, so its usually best to go for stability before efficiency.

If the indentation is the same for the whole file, you can do a simple String.replaceAll() and replace newlines with a newline followed by a number of spaces. If you need dynamic indentation, you probably need to parse (find) where the indentation level changes, check each character if its  newline or indentation level change, buy now it's getting complicated...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution. This approach **replaces all newlines with indentation**. Indenting a level requires an `indent()` call. To unindent, call the `unindent()` method.

```
public class IndentPrintWriter extends java.io.PrintWriter
{
  private boolean newLine;
  private String singleIndent = "    ";
  private String currentIndent = "";

  public IndentPrintWriter(Writer pOut, String indent)
  {
    super(pOut);
    this.singleIndent = indent;
  }

  public void indent()
  {
    currentIndent += singleIndent;
  }

  public void unindent()
  {
    if (currentIndent.isEmpty()) return;
    currentIndent = currentIndent.substring(0, currentIndent.length() -   singleIndent.length());
  }

  @Override
  public void print(String pString)
  {
    // indent when printing at the start of a new line
    if (newLine)
    {
      super.print(currentIndent);
      newLine = false;
    }

    // strip the last new line symbol (if there is one)
    boolean endsWithNewLine = pString.endsWith("\n");
    if (endsWithNewLine) pString = pString.substring(0, pString.length() - 1);

    // print the text (add indent after new-lines)
    pString = pString.replaceAll("\n", "\n" + currentIndent);
    super.print(pString);

    // finally add the stripped new-line symbol.
    if (endsWithNewLine) println();
  }

  @Override
  public void println()
  {
    super.println();
    newLine = true;
  }
}
```